# elastic search dsl: filter is not working as it should be

Tags: elasticsearch

I am doing a POST with below obj as body parameter which is supposed to get results and filter them according to their category:

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [{"term": {"some_category": "SOME CATEGORY Value"}}
      ],
      "should": [
        {"match": {"field_1": "Some value"}},
        {"match": {"field_2": "Some value"}}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove the filter its working but not filtering as expected.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong or tell me the query which I should be using?

This syntax is suggested in the docs as well but still, it's not working.

Here is the [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-filter-context.html) which directed me to this type of query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are applying term query on `'text'` field `'some_category'`. You should query on the `'keyword'` type of the field `'some_category'` - `'some_category.keyword'`

```
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "some_category.keyword": "SOME CATEGORY Value"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "field_1": "Some value"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "field_2": "Some value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working. I've similar situation where term query is not working in must/filter.